# Making a comparator between two results

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, set

Comparing Values of Two data structure. Basically I want to compare my output result which is in string format with the values of Three hashmaps.

One data Structure contains three hashmaps:

```
<Key, Set<SuperClass>>
<key, Set<SubClass>>
<key,Set<EquivalentClass>> datatype.
```

Other data structure is a Class that contains three sets and one element and give the result in String format

```
{SuperClassSet, SubClassClassSet, EquivalentClassSet and keyElement}.
```

Situation is Key is same in both data structure. I have to compare the Set values of key in DataImplementation Class against the Set Values of key in Hashmaps. As both must contain the same setValues. I also want to print the result with differences in values if occurs. I tried to start something like this but not getting how to start with:

```
Public void testing(DataImplementationClass FinalGraphList)
{
For(DataImplementationClass owlElement: FinalGraphList){
    if(owlelement.getSuccessor() equals hashmap.get(OwlElement).getSuccessor()){ 
        iterate all successors element of DataImplementationClass in HashMap Successor Set
    }
    Else{
        System.out.println(owlelement+ "Do something");
    }

    if(owlelement.getPredecessor() equals hashmap.get(OwlElement).getPredecessor()){ 
        iterate all Predecessor elements of DataImplementationClass in HashMap Predecessor Set
    }
    Else{
        System.out.println(owlelement+ "Need to check");
    }

    if(owlelement.getEquEquivalent() of DataImplementationClass in HashMap EquivalentSet()){
        iterate all Equivalent element of DataImplementationClass in HashMap EquivalentSet
    }
    Else{
        System.out.println(owlelement+ "Need to check");
    }
    }   
}
```

Actual Code of DataImplementation Class and HashMap:

```
//Three hashmap used to compare the result of class DataimplementationClass
static HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>> subClassSet = new HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>>();
static HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>> superClassSet = new HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>>();
static HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>> equiClassMap = new HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>>();


// Final Output Data implementation class use for final graph data structure

package MainOWLFiles;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DataImplementationCls {

public Set<OWLClass> predcessorElements;
public Set<OWLClass> successorElements;
public OWLClass element;
public Set<OWLClass> isEquivalentList;


public Set<OWLClass> getIsEquivalentList() {
    return isEquivalentList;
}

public void setIsEquivalentList(Set<OWLClass> isEquivalentList) {
    this.isEquivalentList = isEquivalentList;
}

public DataImplementationCls(OWLClass element) {
    this.element = element;
    predcessorElements = new HashSet<OWLClass>();
    successorElements = new HashSet<OWLClass>();
    this.isEquivalentList = new HashSet();

}

public Set<OWLClass> getPredcessorElements() {
    return predcessorElements;
}

public void setPredcessorElements(Set<OWLClass> predcessorElements) {
    this.predcessorElements = predcessorElements;
}

public Set<OWLClass> getSuccessorElements() {
    return successorElements;
}

public void setSuccessorElements(Set<OWLClass> successorElements) {
    this.successorElements = successorElements;
}

public OWLClass getElement() {
    return element;
}

public void setElement(OWLClass element) {
    this.element = element;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DataImplementationCls [predcessorElements=" + predcessorElements + ", "
            + "successorElements=" + successorElements + ", "
            + "element=" + element + ", "
            + "isEquivalent=" + isEquivalentList + ""
            + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some real code?

Comment: "data structure is a string that contains three sets" what do you mean with that? How can a string contain three sets? And a key apparently.

Comment: @shmosel: I posted the actual code. I have a dataimplementation Class which gives result in String format and other side I have three hashmaps. I need to make a comparator to compare the values of String result against hashmaps.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: I posted my Data Structure class that returns a String as result which i need to Compare against the hashmaps values.

Comment: Classes don't return values, methods do. Which one is returning your string? And in what way are you trying to compare it?

Comment: shmosel: Thanks to correct me. DataImplementation class is returning the String by calling toString() method. I am trying to compare the result by passing the final result string as a argument.Then by extracting the values using get and set method from DataImplementation Class, I want to compare against HashMap Set values.

Comment: You should remove the OWL tag as this question is simply about Java datastructures.